# Relationship between two different expressions of a surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between finding the tangent plane to the surface $(x,y,f(x,y))$ at a particular point and finding the tangent plane to $g(x,y,z)=c$. I think finding the tangent plane to the latter is very intuitive, but the former I can't seem to boil down to the same type of expression of a surface.

My attempt was to take $f:\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ and find $D$. The answer is $(f_x, f_y)$. But I can't find the relationship between the kernel of that linear transformation and the typical formula for the surface of $(x,y,f(x,y)$ at a particular point.

Answer (score 1):

$(x,y) \mapsto S(x,y)= (x,y,f(x,y))$ can be seen as the parametric definition of a surface in $\mathbb R^3$.

The tangent plane at a point $S(x_0, y_0)$ is a plane that passes trough $S(x_0,y_0)= (x_0,y_0,f(x_0,y_0))$ and contains the tangent vectors $\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0)$, $\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0)$. Therefore if $(x,y,z)$ belongs to that tangent plane, the three vectors $(x-x_0,y-y_0,z-f(x_0,y_0))$, $\frac{\partial S}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0)$ and  $\frac{\partial S}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0)$ are linearly dependent.

Computing the determinant

$$\begin{vmatrix}
x-x_0 & 1 & 0\\
y-y_0 & 0 & 1\\
z-z_0 & \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0) & \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0)
\end{vmatrix} = (x-x_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_0,y_0) + (y-y_0)\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (x_0,y_0) -(z-z_0)$$
enables you to find the equation of the tangent plane.